# Why {} in array not working?

Tags: c, arrays

The proper syntax for error is :

```
arr[n] = {10,20,50,40,80,70,30};
```

But its show an error: "Expression error"

But it is allowing:

```
arr[n] = (10,20,50,40,80,70,30);
```

And also I am not getting the expected output! whats the matter?

```
void main()
{
node *head,*P;
int n,i,arr[];
clrscr();

n=6;
arr[6] = {10,20,50,40,80,70,30};
head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
head->data=arr[0];
head->next = NULL;
P=head;
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
P->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
P=P->next;
P->next=NULL;
P->data=arr[i];
}
P=head;
while(P!=NULL)
{
printf("%d",P->data);
P=P->next;
printf("----->");
}  
getch();
}
```

My C program code!

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: array size must be constant so if you leave arr[] = {10,20,50,40,80,70,30}; it will work

Comment: Its a linked list program... but I don't think it matters.. coz problem seems only in the syntax!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Declare and initialize an array? Then you need to actually declare something (and you cannot initialize VLAs). Or assigning to a single element? Then why do you try to assign multiple elements? Or do try to assign to an array after it's declaration? You'll need a loop or `memcpy` for that.

Comment: I have updated the post! with the code!

Comment: `main` should return `int`. Also, please indent your code.

Answer (score 4):

Because `{}` stands for array intialization. The only accepted way to do that is like that:

```
int arr[] = {10,20,50,40,80,70,30};
```

But the second line way (that works for you) doesn't do what you expect. It's actually a [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). So, this line is similar to

```
arr[n] = 30; // the last expression in a comma operator
```

Comment: showing error! I tried again!

Comment: @user3672971 Can you write more information? Unfortunately, I'm not a psychic. Post your code here.

Comment: Yaa I am updated my post!

Comment: @user3672971 well, array intialization can't be splitted. Try this:
int n,i; int arr[] = {10,20,50,40,80,70,30};

Comment: yaa that worked! thanks and sorry for this stupid post!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make this kind of dynamic initialization for the arrays in C.

You should omit `n` and do:

```
int arr[] = {10,20,50,40,80,70,30};
```

You should not do:

```
int arr[];    //initialization
arr[6] = {10,20,50,40,80,70,30};   //assignment
```

Because, it is not initialization. It is assignment and C does not allow you to do that.

Comment: Show the other related parts of the code then. Problem does not seem to be here.

Comment: Post updated! please check it

Comment: This initialization(as name implies) can only work for initialization. See the edit.